# Solving a circuit using Thevenin's theorem and superposition

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistance, thevenin, superposition

I have the following circuit in an example problem from a book, where it shows you how to find the Rth and the Vth. The Vth has to be found via superposition.

[image]

The Rth solution is Rth = 103/77R, which I can find correctly and I do understand how to get. The problem comes at the time of getting the Vth. When the end result of getting a sub Vth isn't a typical voltage divisor circuit, the resolution book uses these formulas without explaining where they come from.

[image]

I would like to understand how these formulas work.

Comment: *The Vth has to be found via superposition* - no it doesn't; there are several ways.

Comment: I know, the problem just specifies that this particular exercise has to be resolved using only superposition. I understand how to solve this particular exercise using Kirchoff's law, but I would like to understand the logic behind the formulas applied here.

Comment: The logic starts with 1 current loop the add conductances then convert to V eq +Req, repeat next element across nodes , repeat

Comment: Well, I think they have got (1) wrong so it's probably a waste of time trying to address this. Where did the pictures come from. Maybe link the site? Looks like they have (2) wrong as well.